# How to change initial Talkback focus when code Android View in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, talkback

Basically, I am looking for a equivalent in Jetpack Compose of the `sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` used in xml.

Currently, my page looks in this structure:

```
Surface {
   TopToolbarBar() {
     Row() {
       NavigationIcon()
       Title()
       ....
     }
   }
   Card1{
     Row1()
     Column() {
       RowA()
       RowB()
       Button()
     }
   }
   Card2{
     ...
   }
}
```

I would like to place the accessibility focus on the `Button()` instead of `NavigationIcon()` when this page is open. Not sure if there is any workaround to achieve this? I don't think there is an official way to do so.

I know there is a requestFocus() method together with a FocusManager concept. However, I don't think they are useful when it comes to the accessibility `focus`

I tried to set a focusRequester and call requestFocus() inside a LaunchedEffect() block. But it won't work. The inital Talkback focus will stay at the navigation icon, which is the left and top most item of my Compose page.

Any hints? I also found there is a `SemanticsPropertyReceiver.requestFocus` but there is barely a sample that I can use to understand how it works.